# Is it possible to enable the H2O DAI to check variable multicollinearity when building models?

Tags: h2o, driverless-ai

While using H2O DAI to build models, I noticed that in the end model there would be some correlated variables.
For instance, variables "max number of saving accounts in past 9 months" and "max number of saving accounts in past 3 months" both show up in the final model, but they are having a high correlation.
Understand there are ways we can check this prior to feeding the data for H2O DAI, but I am wondering if there is some settings or good way to let H2O DAI check variable multicollinearity automatically while selecting features to build models?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to look at correlated features and manually remove them before building a model. Go to the Autoviz section and look at the [Correlated Scatterplots](http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/datasets-viewing.html#correlated-scatterplots) then drop those columns from the experiment or dataset.

Removing collinear features is difficult for any modeling since you won't know which feature would be better than the other. What if having both "max number of saving accounts in past 9 months" and "max number of saving accounts in past 3 months" make your model perform much better than only having one? This is where domain knowledge becomes important, and the expert should decide.

One way to remove some collinearity is limiting the number of features your model has. You can use `max_orig_cols_selected` to limit the number. You can set it in expert settings or [config.toml (see for more info)](http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/config_toml.html). But as I said before, it's hard to determine whether some collinear features should be kepts over others.

Another option is to use algorithms/models that inherently do feature selection, like L1 (LASSO) regression.

Comment: Thanks for the response Neema, indeed this process is quite subjective and hence expert knowledge should be involved here. Just to share that I have tried to limit the number of variables though "max_orig_cols_selected" as you suggested, but still the highly correlated variables would be included in the final model, guess it means statistically these variables are important to improve the model performance. I am now using some alternative methods to remove some correlated features before importing data into H2O.